# Why awk is not creating files here?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {for(x=1;x<=100;x++){touch st$x}}'
```

I want to create 100 files with this `awk` command: `st1`, `st2`, `st3`, ...`st100`. But it is not creating anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you need awk for? bash: `touch st{1..100}` -- using system() in awk will actually be pretty slow: it will have to launch 100 /bin/sh processes and 100 touch processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your problem

`awk` has its own set of commands and by default it can't execute a shell command like you did.

### Solution

You can use `awk`'s `system()` to execute a shell command inside your `awk` script:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for (x = 1 ; x <= 100 ; ++x) system("touch st" x) }'
```